# How to properly use Deep Link in Getx router?

Tags: flutter, deep-linking, flutter-getx

I've done all the configurations for the deep link in the AndroidManifest.xml and changed the **GetMaterialApp** to **GetMaterialApp.router**.
And when I click on a link to a specific part of the app, it goes.
Soo, the deep link works, but when I click on the BackButton, my screen turns black.
And I don't know why, can someone help me?

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="deep_link_demo"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            

            <meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true"/>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="deeplink-demo.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="deeplink-demo.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
            </intent-filter>


        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The main file

```dart
import 'package:deep_link_demo/app/routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:deep_link_demo/app/ui/pages/unknown/unknown_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp.router(

      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      // initialRoute: AppRoutes.home,

      routeInformationParser: GetInformationParser(
        initialRoute: AppRoutes.splash,
      ),

      routerDelegate: GetDelegate(
        backButtonPopMode: PopMode.Page,
        notFoundRoute: GetPage(
          name: AppRoutes.unknown, 
          page: () => const UnknownPage()
        ),
      ),

      getPages: AppPages.routes,
      
    );
  }
}
```

My Home page

```dart
import 'package:deep_link_demo/app/routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          const Text('Home Page'),
          const SizedBox(height: 20),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: ()=>Get.rootDelegate.toNamed(
              '${AppRoutes.second}/15',
            ), 
            child: const Text('Second Page')
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

And my second page

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  final int id = int.parse(Get.parameters['id']!);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Text('ID: $id'),
          ),
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation. However, I have a preference for using Getx, so I would appreciate additional suggestions on how to address the issue specifically with Getx, rather than opting for an alternative solution.